# Custom Paginated list setting child objects in IQueryable to null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, iqueryable, ef-core-3.1

In my ASP.NET Core web application I fetch `IQueryable<Task>` using Entity Framework Core from my database to a `result` variable in my controller. See data definitions at the end.

If I inspect `result` the `ListTag` is populated as expected and each item in it has it's `User` populated. So, everything is OK.

Before passing the results to a view (`.cshtml`), I want to transform the IQueryable to a `PaginatedList` (so as to use pager in my index page). The resulting `PaginatedList` still has child list `ListTag` populated, but its `User` is `NULL`.

Why?

Note: in the repository I use both `Include(x => x.ListTag)` and `ThenInclude(u => u.User)` when fetching data from the database.

All the code and data definitions (short):

Get paginated list:

```cs
indexModel.ListTasks = await PaginatedList<DetailModel>.CreateAsync(result.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber, pageSize);
```

`PaginatedList` class:

```cs
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get { return (PageIndex > 1); }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get { return (PageIndex < TotalPages); }
    }

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

Entity Framework Core data models:

```cs
class Task
{
    public int IdTask 
    public string Subject

    public List<Tag> ListTag 
}

class Tag
{
    public int IdTag 
    public string Tag

    [ForeignKey("IdTask")]
    public Task Task{ get; set; }

    public int IdUser 
    [ForeignKey("IdUser")]
    public User User
}

class User
{
    public int IdUser 
    public string Name
}
```

Index and Detail model (for the cshtml views):

```cs
class IndexModel
{
    public Helpers.PaginatedList<DetailModel> ListTasks
}

class DetailModel
{
    public int IdTask 
    public string Subject
    public List<Tag> ListTag 
}
```

EDIT 1: deleted (irrelevant)

**EDIT 2**

I found the problem and solution (I think). What I was doing is first fetching data from the database (repository) and doing a select into the DetailModel variable:

```cs
var result = _tasks.List(searchString);
    .Select(item => new DetailModel
    {
        IdTask = item.IdTask ,
        Subject = item.Subject,
        ListTag = item.ListTag,
    });
```

and passing `result` in PaginatedList and then to my view. Apparently the users got lost in the "reflection": `ListTag=item.ListTag`.

If I just change the order of things and firt fetch from database into a temp variable, pass the temp variable to the PaginatedList and then select into local DetailModel variable everything is OK. Users are populated.

```cs
var temp = _tasks.List(searchString);
var temp2 = await PaginatedList<Task>.CreateAsync(temp.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber, pageSize);

var result = temp2
    .Select(item => new DetailModel
    {
        IdTask = item.IdTask ,
        Subject = item.Subject,
        ListTag = item.ListTag,
    });.ToList();
```

Comment: this looks like involving just the `result` so almost your posted code is irrelevant. Have you tried debugging to see what the `result.ToList()` contains? it should have users there. Otherwise something is wrong with the query which should have been what posted.

Comment: Code looks ok. Something wrong in other place.

Comment: @KingKing: I've tried debugging and `result.ToList()` contains populated `User`, so `result` is not the problem. Anything alse I can check?

Comment: @TheMixy, then just test `result.AsNoTracking().Skip(0).Take(1).ToList()` if problem still occur - it is EF limitation.

Comment: this is not your real code, `ListTasks` is an `IQueryable<DetailModel>` (as what you posted) which is ***strange*** but it's even weirder when you can set it to a `List<DetailModel>` by this `indexModel.ListTasks = await PaginatedList<DetailModel>.CreateAsync` - ***Please*** post your real code, don't try to assume that you understand the problem and just post the code you imagine.

Comment: @KingKing: you're right, ListTasks is of type `PaginatedList`. I edited my code above. And yes, it is not my real code. Like it's written in my question the code is shortened otherwise the post/question would be too long

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: if I do `var test = result.AsNoTracking().Skip(0).Take(1).ToList();` then `User` is null

Comment: if `result` contains `users` expectedly, there must be some point after that when the users are unexpectedly set to `null` all. That means you can only debug it to find that point. Step from the `var items = await source.Skip ...`. How you do verify that the users are null?

Comment: are you sure that all `Tag`s have a non-null `User`? A wrong assumption can cause you think it's a bug but may actually not. I don't think `result.AsNoTracking()` can remove all the includes, skip & take just filter the records set.

Comment: I have `var result = List((bool)checkBox, (bool)checkBox2, searchString);` and `result` is populated as expected. Now in the next line (nothing else in between) I added `var test = result.AsNoTracking().Skip(0).Take(1).ToList();`. And if I put a break point after this line and inspect both elements `result` is stil fine, but `test` does not have populated `User`

Comment: @TheMixy `in the repository I use both ...` what repository? Are you sure the problem isn't that code? `Skip(0)` is meaningless and easy to avoid with `query=pageIndex>1?query.Skip(..):query`. Missing related entities mean that `Include` calls are missing. That's the code you need to post. You should inspect the SQL generated by EF too, as paging over a *graph* is completely different from paging over flat results. EF doesn't know you're paging, so it will generate a single query with JOINs that may return just half of each root object's children.

Comment: @TheMixy for example, if you have 10 root objects with 20 children each, `Skip(25)` would skip the first object's children *and* 5 from the second object. If you want to page the root objects only, you need to change your query.

Comment: @TheMixy you'd have the same problem if you used paging in SQL. If you use eg `OFFSET FETCH NEXT` on the results of a JOIN, you're paging over the entire result set, not just the "first" table. If you wanted to page the parent or child table results you'd have to use different queries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: so you're saying that the `PaginatedList` class I use is not OK, when attaching child records to child records of "paged" parents? This doesnt explain why I everything populated when I inspect the `result` while debugging and then set to NULL when using PaginatedList... ??

Comment: @TheMixy the problem isn't the class.  For flat lists, `Skip.Take` are perfect, although paging *requires* ordering, otherwise subsequent pages can easily return duplicate data or miss records. Without `ORDER BY` the server is free to return results in any order. That's why paging queries always include an `ORDER BY` clause. With graphs though, even a graph database wouldn't know what to page. The roots? Children? Grandchildren? `Skip().Take()` applies to the entire query, so it can easily return a root with only half the grandchildren, then the *same* root with the other half

Comment: @TheMixy what *do* you want to display? If you want to display a paged list of tasks with extra details when clicked, you could create one query that loads only `Task`s with some extra aggregated properties (eg tag count), then use AJAX to request detail objects and display with JavaScript. On the server, you can load only a page of root IDs, eg Task IDs, then load the actual objects using `where pageIDs.contains(task.Id)` - page only the IDs, load the entire graph. If you're lazy you could *remove* `Include` and let EF use lazy loading to load the related entities. `Skip` applies only to root

Comment: @TheMixy btw this problem is nothing new - paging over big master/detail reports is a recurring problem, especially once you start having a lot of data.

Comment: I want do display list of Tags. I need User data in the list. I could populate via JS/Ajax, but it doesn't make sense, because I think it should be possible the way I'm trying to do it above. Especially since all the data is actually present in the IQueryable. It's partially disappearing in PaginatedList...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning**

Don't use `Skip` or `Take` unless you really need it. The database server has no idea how many results there are, so it has to create an execution plan that works with paging no matter what.

It's easy to construct the query based on the actual values, eg :

```
if (pageSize>1)
{
    source=source.Skip((pageIndex-1)*pageSize);
};
if (pageSize>0)
{
    source=source.Take(pageSize);
}
```

---

It's unclear what kind of paging is needed (over tasks? tags? users? all of them? what does `all of them` mean?) , but `Skip().Take()` are almost certainly not enough.

`OrderBy().Skip().Take()` in LINQ or `ORDER BY .. OFFSET .. FETCH NEXT` in SQL apply to the entire result set generated by SQL. In fact, EF Core 3+ generates code somewhat like this  :

```
SELECT [a_bunch_of_columns] 
  FROM dbo.Tasks LEFT JOIN dbo.Tags on .....
  ORDER BY [some_column_or_columns] 
  OFFSET @p0 ROWS
  FETCH NEXT @p1 ROWS ONLY;
```

There's no distinction between parents and children, so one page can contain half of a Task's tags and the next page the other half.

**Paging tasks only**

If you want to page over *tasks*, one way to do it is to retrieve pages of the IDs, then retrieve the full objects based on the IDs. This can [improve performance dramatically](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch) when the retrieved columns aren't covered by an index.

You could write something like this to retrieve one page of Task IDs at a time, then load the full objects:

```
var pageIDs=await dbContext.Tasks
                           .Select(t=>t.IdTask)
                           .OrderBy(t=>t.IdTask)
                           .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
                           .Take(pageSize)
                           .ToListAsync();
var tasks=await dbContext.Tasks
                         .Where(t=>pageIds.Contains(t.IdTask))
                         .OrderBy(t=>t.IdTask)
                         .ToListAsync();
```

**Using explicit loading**

Another option is to page the Tasks then use [Explicit loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit) to load the related entities. You'll have to call `Load` on each `Task` instance though, which results in `pagesize` queries :

```
var tasks=await dbContext.Tasks
                           .OrderBy(t=>t.IdTask)
                           .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
                           .Take(pageSize)
                           .ToListAsync();
foreach(var task in tasks)
{
    dbContext.Entry(tasks)
             .Collection(b => b.Tags)
             .Load();
}
```

This paragraph suggests you may be able to use a single query, although I haven't found an example yet:

> You can also explicitly load a navigation property by executing a separate query that returns the related entities. If change tracking is enabled, then when query materializes an entity, EF Core will automatically set the navigation properties of the newly loaded entity to refer to any entities already loaded, and set the navigation properties of the already-loaded entities to refer to the newly loaded entity.

Assuming change tracking is enabled, you may be able to load and attach related tags with the following code. I haven't tried this though and I'm not sure how efficient the generated query would be :

```
var tasks=await dbContext.Tasks
                           .OrderBy(t=>t.IdTask)
                           .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
                           .Take(pageSize)
                           .ToListAsync();
var ids=tasks.Select(t=>t.IdTask).ToList();
var tags=await dbContext.Tags
                        .Include(t=>t.User)
                        .Where(t=>ids.Contains(t.Task.IdTask))
                        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: thank you for a detailed reply. I want to page over Tasks. But in the case above it is of no importance, because currently my PageSize=9999 and there are only 3 tasks that meet my search criteria (and less than 100 in total in the DB)

Comment: since there is no paging actually being done (PageSize > all DB records count) why am I gettting NULL? What is the point of being able to use ThenInclude, if it does not work?

Comment: @TheMixy why are you using paging at all then ? As for what's going on, the `Include` code is missing. You only posted the paging code. Nobody can tell you what's wrong with eager loading without the DbContext configuration, your actual code and most importantly, the SQL queries. Even `Skip(0)` can change the query.

Comment: @TheMixy what happens when you *don't* use paging? If `User` is still missing, the problem is in the repository code

Comment: not using paging works - see my workaround above.

Comment: PageSize=9999 is what I changed the variable to when looking for the problem

Comment: @TheMixy not using paging is not a workaround, that should be the primary option. `Skip` and `Take` change your query and affect its execution. I can't tell you why some `User` properties are `null` without knowing what the data looks like or what the queries were. Perhaps `User` is optional and the page you loaded had no `User` instances? What are the queries?

Comment: Hmm, now I see that the actual SQL generated does not include JOIN to User table (despite using TheInclude). Why?

Comment: To much code to share here. Thank you anyway. Apparently an EF issue. I'll find some other working workaround.

Comment: Maybe, if you use an old EF Core version, and if there's not something fishy in the repository code. This paging code is problematic though. If you don't want paging you should use it to begin with. Using `Skip(0)` doesn't result in reusable code, it forces every query to pay a paging tax, by forcing the server to use a different execution plan. The server doesn't know how many results there are so it *has* to buffer results until the page limit is reached.

Comment: I'm not sure how your comment reflects the fact that EF is completely omitting using JOIN to a class/table explicitely referenced via ThenInclude?

Comment: I can't tell you what's going on without the code. In most cases where people think there's a library bug, it turns out something was missed in the code. I'd have to create a new project with those classes and assumed tables just to try and replicate what you described. It would be a *lot* easier and faster if you posted a *minimal* example that reproduces the problem (ie no repositories, just DbContext code)

Comment: I work on a project for one financial institution so it's a bit "hard" to share code. I'll simplify the project (re-run it to ensure the problem still remains) and post the code. Give me a couple of hours please. Can I send the code just to you as file (something.txt)?

Comment: @TheMixy it's not - I've worked on algos, and a lot of stuff is common practice so nobody can claim copyright or trade secrets. Some times it's `I can't believe you're iterating the entire array to find the last price` that people want to hide. Not a joke either: I took over code that did just that, with C++ for "speed", instead of iterating from the end. Nobody can blame you for posting code that already exists on hundreds of blogs and docs already

Comment: @TheMixy that won't prevent tech-challenged managers from making noise though.

Comment: Can you check my EDIT2 above. It works this way, but is it the right way?